# Installing OEM usb driver

Tags: android

I am taking a course on how to build apps with android and I am trying to install the OED usb driver. I have a  motorola and the course provides a link to the motorola website but I'm not sure exactly what I have to install. [Is it this](https://motorola-global-en-uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/89881)? If not can someone please provide a link to the correct website.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Win7

Comment: Tried that! But when you click the link to the Motorola website it takes you to the main page rather then to a link to download the usb driver

Comment: @suli link you have mentioned seems correct bcoz it say : Motorola Device Manager contains USB drivers and software to connect your Motorola phone or tablet to your computer using a USB cable. Try that in case you face issue post that problem here